# How can I render animation in seconds?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am using cycle and I had rendered my animation thinking it would take less than a minute, but my render time is an hour+. I use a MacBook Air M2 2022. My sample count is 8192, while my noise threshold is 0.03. Max bounces total is 12, and indirect light under clamping is 0. I’m a beginner and I’ll be doing 3d a lot. Is there a way to make my render go fast per frames? Should I get a graphic card, if so what graphic card is best to use.

Comment: Highly depends on the scene and what you are willing to give up for speed, but 8192 samples is definitely not a short-render-time amount of samples. If speed it a concern, why not use Eevee?

Comment: well...tbh a sample number of 8192 is....extremely high. Put that down a lot like to 50 and you will see significantly quicker renders. And one thing is for sure: you always change speed against quality. So reduce it as far as you are satisfied with the result quality.

Comment: @Chris thanks so much, but if reducing samples loses the quality is there anyway I can quicken render with graphic cards and if so what’s best. I’m doing the donut tutorial like most beginners and the teacher uses an Apple laptop however his render took him seconds and mine hours. I’m guessing he has a graphic card and I’m eager to know which is best.

Comment: @L0Lock thanks for the help. I did get to read through it and most didn’t change anything. The tutor was using an Apple product not sure if it was a desktop or a MacBook but his rendering took seconds. I noticed he used GPU and he had CUBA enabled in he’s cycle but I don’t have that and I’m sure it’s from a graphic card however it’s nividia and Apple doesn’t use that so how does he have it? And what graphic card can I use to get the same results?

Comment: maybe watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNiobzflmpA

Comment: @VanessaAdazie: just try it - set samples to 100. I am sure the quality is still pretty good. it is worse quality, but most of the times you can hardly see it (except you are a perfectionist). i render most of my animations with even lower samples...